# Proof with integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Question 1 Show that $\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi
> > \:^2}}e^{-\frac{\left(x-m\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=m$
>
> Ok so from what I understand we can use this equation to prove it
>    $\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=1$

So I integrated it and got
 $\frac{1}{2}\text{}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+C$

Is this the right step so far?

But then what do I do from here?

> Question 2 show that  $\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi
> > \:\sigma^2}}\left(x-m\right)^2e^{-\frac{\left(x-m\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=\sigma^2$

Comment: How did you do the definite integral and end up with an expression containing the variable you were integrating with respect to, and a constant?

Comment: Can you double check that you've transcribed the problem correctly?  As it's written it asks you to problem something false.  Also, reformat it to put the entire problem (both parts) first, then your work.  Use the `>` markdown for the problem, not your work.   Finally, I think `\sigma` is the intended symbol in place of `o`.

Comment: corrected it, and @AlkaKadri I used substitution and then computed the boundaries with limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowed to use the fact that
$$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\ dx =1$$
Now if we replace $x$ with $\frac{x - m}{\sigma}$ we still have $\frac{x - m}{\sigma} \to \pm\infty$ as $x \to \pm\infty$, and
$$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{\left(\frac{x - m}{\sigma}\right)^2}{2}}\ d\left(\frac{x - m}{\sigma}\right) =1$$
Then observe that since $\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{x - m}{\sigma}\right) = \frac{1}{\sigma} \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{\sigma}\ dx = d\left(\frac{x - m}{\sigma}\right)$, we also have
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{\left(\frac{x - m}{\sigma}\right)^2}{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sigma}\ dx &= 1\\
\Rightarrow\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(x- m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\ dx &= 1
\end{align}
So as people have commented on your original post, something is definitely wrong with what you've transcribed/read here...

Comment: i edit it, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

The question itself is wrong. If $m=0$ it says that the integral of a strictly positive function is $0$!. The formula becomes correct if you multiply the integrand by $x$. In that case write $x$ as $(x-m) +m$, split the integral into two parts. In the first part make the substitution $y=x-m$ and use the fact that the integral of an odd function is $0$. Can you compute the second term? Finally, for the variance part you have to follows the same method ans use integration by parts.